# SSL certificate for site on Amazon ec2 possible?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, http, ssl-certificate

we're thinking of getting an application hosted on the ec2 service, and the application's documentation says that an SSL certificate can be installed for secure communication (https).

Its not clear to me whether a site hosted there can have one installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSL certificates specify a domain name or names, not an IP address. I have not used an SSL certificate on an EC2 host, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

You will probably want to use Amazon's Elastic IP service so that you can maintain a stable relationship between a given EC2 instance (EBS-backed, I imagine) and the publicly visible hostname; the hostname is what's described in the certificate.

Obviously, installing the private key for an SSL keypair on someone else's hardware has security implications - but I bet that the majority of SSL private keys are sitting on hardware that's not owned by the holder of the certificate, so it's not like that's an unfamiliar or unusual risk.

Low-end certificates aren't very expensive these days - most of the certificate vendors will even issue you a temporary 30-day cert for free so you can experiment with it and see how it will work out in your environment. You can also use a self-signed certificate which will probably generate complaints from browsers.

Comment: But why it is that some webhosting services force you to buy an IP address if you want to have an SSL certificate installed on your domain?

Comment: Non-SSL virtual hosts work by including a "Host:" header in the HTTP request that tells the server what (virtual) host the request is intended for. This means that many domains can be handled on a single IP address; the server figures out how to respond by looking at the Host: header.

The traditional setup for SSL connections meant that it was necessary to negotiate the cryptographic aspects of the communication before the HTTP request could be presented to the host. This meant that the only way to differentiate between requests for the same server was to use one IP address per virtual host.

Comment: So are you saying that one IP address *IS* required for an SSL certificate? The way I understand the Amazon system is that its all just one big virtual hosting provider - I know that a dedicated IP is NOT possible at Amazon, so by the above the SSL cert shouldn't work as well...?

Comment: A dedicated IP is possible with EC2, that's what Elastic IP does. The IP address you get with an EC2 server (non-Elastic IP) is not shared with others at the time that you're using it, but will be reused after your EC2 instance is deleted.

Comment: So a _fixed/static/dedicated_ IP address is NOT required...

Comment: A dedicated IP address is required unless you're using SNI, which is relatively new and not supported by all browsers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication and http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4366.txt . The IP address doesn't need to be fixed or static, but it would be easier to set up a durable EC2 instance if you used an Elastic IP (giving you effectively a static IP) because you won't have to update your DNS records every time the EC2 instance changes.

Answer (score 5):

Further to @gbroiles' answer above, I'm running a site for my company which is hosted on EC2 and has an SSL certificate.  EC2 gives you full access to the operating system, so I just installed the certificate in our Apache server in exactly the same way as if it was running on a physical machine.

We use an elastic IP address as described above; Amazon doesn't charge for elastic IP's if they are in use, but there is a small charge for unused elastic IP addresses.  See the [AWS pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your input gareth - having someone doing exactly that is very reassuring!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it - Amazon's EC2 hosting provides an "elastic IP" which is a dedicated IP address for as long as you need it. If you no longer need it, I'm assuming you no longer need the SSL cert!

Installation won't be as easy as through a GUI on Plesk or CPanel etc, but it's pretty straightforward via your terminal - in fact, when you purchase an SSL Certificate, they usually run through the instructions on their website for installation on linux or whatever.